# How to make accordion stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would one make an accordion tab remain open, giving it an active state?

Ie., if I was on the List One accordion page, then that accordion would be open upon entering the page, and the other accordion would be closed.

I've created [a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2krm/) of where I am so far. I've tried a few different methods but it just seems to stop the accordion from working altogether.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="trigger-button"><span>List One</span></div>
        <div class="accordion">
                <ul>
            <li>Item One</li>
            <li>Item Two</li>
            <li>Item Three</li>
            <li>Item Four</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="trigger-button"><span>List Two</span></div>
        <div class="accordion">
            <ul>
           <li>Item One</li>
           <li>Item Two</li>
           <li>Item Three</li>
           <li>Item Four</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.trigger-button {
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
margin-bottom: 6px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);    
background-color: #CCC;
border: 1px solid #000;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 14px;
cursor:pointer;
text-align: center;
}
.trigger-button span {
padding-left: 0;
}
.trigger-button.active { 
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
}
.accordion {
float: left;
padding: 8px 15px 22px 15px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.trigger-button').click(function() {
    $(".trigger-button").removeClass("active")
    $('.accordion').slideUp('normal');
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(this).addClass("active");
     } 
     });
    $('.accordion').hide();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's also the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). In case you don't want to programming something that has been done that often in the past.

Comment: don't mention my answer. U want to keep track of the state over multiple pages ?

Comment: I need it so that if you are on a page relating to items in List One, then the list one accordion is already open and active when you go to that page. Then if you go to a page with an item relating to List Two then the List Two accordion is already open if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another class to the sections you want to be default open:

```
<div class="accordion open">
```

Then change:

```
$('.accordion').hide();
```

To:

```
$('.accordion:not(.open)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like

`$(this).next().toggelClass('active'); // switch .active class of the .accrodion div`

to your click-handler and run initialization on document.load:

```
$(document).load(function(){    
      $('.accordion').hide();
      $('.accordion.active').show();
});
```

Then you can declaratively set `.active` class for tabs you want to be open after initial page-load.