# JS Accordion to stay open while clicking links

Tags: javascript, html

I am using php to get items from a database and generate a html-table to list each item.

To the left of the html-table I have a side-menu with a accordion-function made in javascript.

Inside of each accordion there are links for various search-parameters for sorting the table. For example a link to each Genre.

If I click on one of the accordions, for example "All Genres A-Z", it expands and lists all the genres. But if I then click on one of the links WITHIN the accordion, the page resets naturally and the accordion closes because the page reloads (with the new search parameters).

My accordion is based out of the following question: [How to make accordion stay open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672400/how-to-make-accordion-stay-open), But since all my links are search parameters that leads to the same page (browse.php) I cannot use the same solution that was presented in that question.

**- Is there a way to keep the selected accordion open even after clicking on one of the links within it?**

Here is a good example of how I want it to behave (The menu on the left) [47Admin bootstrap theme](http://geedmo.com/?item=47Admin)

The js:

```
$('.trigger-button').click(function() {
    $(".trigger-button").removeClass("active")
    $('.accordion').slideUp('normal');
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(this).addClass("active");
     } 
 });
$('.accordion').hide();
```

The html on browse.php:

```
<div class='trigger-button'>Favorite Genres</div>
<div class='accordion'>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='browse.php&genre=drama'>Drama</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class='trigger-button'>All Genres A-Z</div>
<div class='accordion'>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='browse.php&genre=drama'>Drama</a></li>
      <li><a href='browse.php&genre=thriller'>Thriller</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[Link to the fiddle used in the other question](http://jsfiddle.net/F2krm/)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you meant `link` for `List One` and `List Two`. Then here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qask4eu8/)

**EDIT:**

In General page reload reset all state in javascript. Basically you have to do reverse operation in page load

1. Pick url in address bar.
2. Match with href attribute in anchor tag.
3. Then expand respective accordion.

And you can do it in PHP code as well by setting classes in element which you want to open. However, I feel handling this in PHP bit noisy.

Hope following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf88w629/) give some idea to you

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite follow you.

Comment: did you checked fiddle in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did. It does not solve my problem. The accordion still closes when i click on a link within it. I shall try to elaborate on my initial question a bit more.

Comment: I think, there is some misunderstanding. The expectation is, if I click `List one`, then it should open. Now if I click `List two`, then `List Two` should get open and `List one` should remains with open state. Please confirm

Comment: No that is not what I want. I still want `List One` to close when I click on `List Two`. But INSIDE `List One` there are `links`. When I click on those, I still want `List One` to be open.

Comment: If this is the case, then there is no change require in older fiddle code. Any way, I have created another fiddler with anchor tag `List one` and `List two`. Please checkout following fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/c7Lt1ugh/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97429/discussion-between-hilarudeens-and-stim).