# How do I keep accordion open at the start of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

How would one make an accordion tab remain open, giving it an active state?

For example, if I was on the accordion page, then all accordion tabs would be open upon entering the page.

I've created a JS Fiddle of where I am so far. I've tried a few different methods but it just seems to stop the accordion from working altogether.

I have tried following this thread with no success:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672400/how-to-make-accordion-stay-open)

Here is a link to my JSF:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpnoiboix/v4k5q12r/7/)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (!panel) {
      panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    }
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #6a1b77;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #6a1b77;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
  color: #6a1b77;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropship-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.responsive-iframe-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">How to sign up for a Sexy Living Drop Shipping account</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="dropship-container">
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe-2" width="1280" height="720" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Intro.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">How to connect the Sexy Living: Adult Dropshipping App to your Shopify store</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="dropship-container">
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe-2" width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping Tutorial - Signup.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">How to connect your Shopify store to the Sexy Living: Adult Dropshipping App</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="dropship-container">
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe-2" width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping tutorial - importing.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Learn about the functionality and how to add products to your store using the Sexy Living: Adult Dropshipping App</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="dropship-container">
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe-2" width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping Tutorial - Connecting.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">For our existing customers who have already downloaded our products through CSV or XLSX files. </div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="dropship-container">
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe-2" width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping Tutorial - Conecting.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to me that when accordion(panel) is open it gets `max-height` on `panel` element and you are setting this with `javascript` so if you want it open when you open page give it `max-height` and when you click on accordion remove `height`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I added a class `stateOpened` to the accordion element that you want opened when the page is loaded and only elements with this class will be opened. I call the function that open an accordion (in your original code the function was anonymous, now I'm using a function named `toggleStatePanel`) only on elements with the class `stateOpened` when the page is loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",loadHappened);

function loadHappened(){
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  if(acc[i].classList.contains("stateOpened"))
  toggleStatePanel.call(acc[i]);
}
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", toggleStatePanel);
}

function toggleStatePanel(){

this.classList.toggle("active");
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (!panel) {
panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
}
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
} 
}
```

```css
.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #6a1b77;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
font-weight: 600;
margin-bottom: 0px;
} 


.active, .accordion:hover {
background-color: #ccc;
}  
.accordion:after {
content: '\002B';
color: #6a1b77;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
font-size: 20px;
}   
.active:after {
content: "\2212";
color: #6a1b77;
    }
.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropship-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.responsive-iframe-2 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
HTML
<div class="accordion stateOpened">How to sign up for a Sexy Living Drop Shipping account</div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="dropship-container active">
<iframe class="responsive-iframe-2"width="1280" height="720" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Intro.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">How to connect the Sexy Living: Adult Dropshipping App to your Shopify store</div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="dropship-container">
<iframe class="responsive-iframe-2"width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping Tutorial - Signup.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">How to connect your Shopify store to the Sexy Living: Adult Dropshipping App</div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="dropship-container">
<iframe class="responsive-iframe-2"width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping tutorial - importing.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">Learn about the functionality and how to add products to your store using the Sexy Living: Adult Dropshipping App</div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="dropship-container">
<iframe class="responsive-iframe-2"width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping Tutorial - Connecting.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">For our existing customers who have already downloaded our products through CSV or XLSX files. </div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="dropship-container">
<iframe class="responsive-iframe-2"width="1280" height="682" src="https://sexyliving.com/wp-content/themes/sexyliving/video/dropship/Dropshipping Tutorial - Conecting.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```